# Flap disc vs sand paper vs grinding disc

Tags: cutting

Assuming a notional 4.5" disc, on a common 4.5" angle grinder:

Which abrasive cuts faster, a flap disc, a sanding disc or a grinding wheel of common grit (I believe 36 or 40)?

Assume, at least for the sanding disc, and the flap disc that the abrasive material are similar, for example, aluminum oxide.  Ditto for the grinding disc, however they do not seem to be as clearly marked as to the abrasive material.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of variables to say which cuts "faster" , but generally IMHO, grinding wheel > flap disk > sanding disk as far as material removal in lets say mild steel.

Comment: Interesting. I find my cut speed with a grinding wheel is lower than with flap disc, and thanks for your observation.  I understand that there are lots of variables, but I am just looking for rough order approximations.

Comment: Your welcome! Yeah, that's my general order. I tend to use flap disks for finishing after grinding with a wheel so my disks are usually a finer grit or I press down lighter with the tool as im just blending in the surfaces by then. The flap disks may even cut faster like you say, but I use the grinding wheel for the "heavy lifting" to save the life of the more expensive flap disks and to try and put less heat into the part until necessary as I feel flap disks cut hotter than wheels. Im not a professional fabricator, more of a machinist so take it for what it is!